# CASE (Contains) rather than equal statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is there a method to use contain rather than equal in case statement?

For example, I am checking a database table has an entry

```
lactulose, Lasix (furosemide), oxazepam, propranolol, rabeprazole, sertraline,
```

Can I use

```
CASE When dbo.Table.Column = 'lactulose' Then 'BP Medication' ELSE '' END AS 'BP Medication'
```

This did not work.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

```
CASE WHEN ', ' + dbo.Table.Column +',' LIKE '%, lactulose,%' 
  THEN 'BP Medication' ELSE '' END AS [BP Medication]
```

The leading `', '` and trailing `','` are added so that you can handle the match regardless of where it is in the string (first entry, last entry, or anywhere in between).

That said, why are you storing data you want to search on as a comma-separated string? This violates all kinds of forms and best practices. You should consider normalizing your schema.

In addition: don't use `'single quotes'` as identifier delimiters; this syntax is deprecated. Use `[square brackets]` (preferred) or `"double quotes"` if you must. See "string literals as column aliases" here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662%28SQL.100%29.aspx

**EDIT** If you have multiple values, you can do this (you can't short-hand this with the other `CASE` syntax variant or by using something like `IN()`):

```
CASE 
  WHEN ', ' + dbo.Table.Column +',' LIKE '%, lactulose,%' 
  WHEN ', ' + dbo.Table.Column +',' LIKE '%, amlodipine,%' 
  THEN 'BP Medication' ELSE '' END AS [BP Medication]
```

If you have more values, it might be worthwhile to use a split function, e.g.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitStrings(@List NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
   RETURN ( SELECT DISTINCT Item FROM
       ( SELECT Item = x.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
         FROM ( SELECT [XML] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>'
         + REPLACE(@List,',', '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
           ) AS a CROSS APPLY [XML].nodes('i') AS x(i) ) AS y
       WHERE Item IS NOT NULL
   );
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.[Table](ID INT, [Column] VARCHAR(255));
GO

INSERT dbo.[Table] VALUES
(1,'lactulose, Lasix (furosemide), oxazepam, propranolol, rabeprazole, sertraline,'),
(2,'lactulite, Lasix (furosemide), lactulose, propranolol, rabeprazole, sertraline,'),
(3,'lactulite, Lasix (furosemide), oxazepam, propranolol, rabeprazole, sertraline,'),
(4,'lactulite, Lasix (furosemide), lactulose, amlodipine, rabeprazole, sertraline,');

SELECT t.ID
  FROM dbo.[Table] AS t
  INNER JOIN dbo.SplitStrings('lactulose,amlodipine') AS s
  ON ', ' + t.[Column] + ',' LIKE '%, ' + s.Item + ',%'
  GROUP BY t.ID;
GO
```

Results:

```
ID
----
1
2
4
```

Comment: This works great, thanks for the advice regarding normalization, will do.  Is there a way to add OR to the statement, for example LIKE '%, lactulose,%' OR '% amlodipine %'.  Thanks again

Comment: Yes just do CASE WHEN ... LIKE ... OR ... LIKE ... you can't do it without repeating the first expression. I will post an example later that deals with multiple values.

Answer (score 7):

Pseudo code, something like:

```
CASE
  When CHARINDEX('lactulose', dbo.Table.Column) > 0 Then 'BP Medication'
ELSE ''
END AS 'Medication Type'
```

This does not care where the keyword is found in the list and avoids depending on formatting of spaces and commas.

Comment: Well first Instr is from VB and not SQL. Also to "not care" about formatting, spaces and commas means thatyou will get false positives if the string is `'bipolar, bilactulose, foo'`...

Comment: Agreed about false positives in case the keyword is a substring of a data-word. The way to avoid this (other than proper normalization) is to use a separator that is more obvious than ', '; maybe '|' or '@'.

Comment: Red herring. The separator isn't what would cause a false positive with your solution. Notice how you would get `'BP Medication'` for the row that contains `'bilactulose'` even though that row doesn't contain the word you're looking for (`'lactulose'`)? I don't think the OP's intention is to match partial words.