# Select next word after string (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string, t-sql

I am currently working with a large dataset of strings. I appreciate SQL isn't ideal for string manipulation but its my only option.

My original table essentially took a string of the form `'company name [+place name] [+ other text]'` and matched it against a list of place names. If there was a match it, stripped the place name and put it in a separate column i.e.

```
Daves butchers London | Daves butchers | London
```

This works fine for all my entries except those which are of the form

```
Duke of Westminster | Duke of | Westminster
```

Is there a way of querying a table so that when column 2 ends with the word 'of' I search column one for the word after of and insert it at the end of column 2?

```
Duke of Westminster | Duke of Westminster | Westminster
```

In particular, it is often the case that the place name is not at the end of column 1,  i.e.

```
Duke of Westminster 0177263774 | Duke of | Westminster
```

Is is still possible in this case?

My dataset has 40,000,000 rows in it and I'm not in a position to rebuild it - I simply have to try and fix the problem.

Comment: are there any with multiple occurrences of the word of?

Comment: How many [duchies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duchies_in_England) are there to start with? Isn't it feasible to simply update manually all the dukes and be done with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select 'This is a test of concept with other words' as [Column1]
    ,'This is a test of ' as [Column2]
    Into #Tmp

SELECT * 
,CASE WHEN RIGHT(RTRIM(Column2),3)=' of' 
THEN Column2+SubString(Column1, PATINDEX('% of %',Column1)+4, 
                       CHARINDEX(' '
                         ,Column1 
                         ,(PATINDEX('% of %',Column1)+4) - PATINDEX('% of %',Column1)+4))
ELSE Column2 END
FROM #tmp

drop table #tmp
```

this assumes that you are working with the first occurrence of 'OF' from Col1

Comment: I used this answer but with the length part of the Substring (last argument) bracketed slightly differently: 
`(CHARINDEX(' ',Column1,PATINDEX('% of %',Column1)+4))
-(PATINDEX('% of %',Column1)+4)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do sth like

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(rownum INT NOT NULL identity(1,1),splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END

SELECT top 1 * FROM dbo.fnSplitString('Duke of Westminster',' ')
WHERE rownum=2 AND splitdata='of'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give the following function a try.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SplitInput
( 
    @input NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(name NVARCHAR(MAX), place NVARCHAR(MAX)) 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @index1 INT
    DECLARE @index2 INT

    SET @index1 = patindex('% of %', @input)
    IF @index1 > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @index2 = patindex('% %', substring(@input, @index1 + 4, len(@input))) + @index1 + 3
        IF @index2 > @index1 + 3
            INSERT INTO
                @output
            VALUES
                (left(@input, @index2 - 1), substring(@input, @index1 + 4, @index2 - @index1 - 4))
        ELSE
            INSERT INTO
                @output
            VALUES
                (@input, substring(@input, @index1 + 4, len(@input)))
    END
    RETURN  
END

SELECT * FROM SplitInput('Duke of Westminster 12345')
SELECT * FROM SplitInput('King of Scotland')
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that employing the CASE statement here is the way to go 
It was already resolved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610412/case-contains-rather-than-equal-statement)

Comment: I'm not convinced.  If you think a case construct will solve this, post the code you think will work.

Comment: Did you look at the link I provided? It's the same issue, same resolution path. CASE WHEN ' ' + dbo.Table.Column +' ' LIKE '% of %' 
  THEN __do what you were doing here but look for the second space instead of the first space__ ELSE __Do what you were doing here__ END AS [BP Medication]